# Can't add routes when adding few routes for a bond

Tags: linux, networking

I am seeing errors when trying to add new routes to the server. Below are the routes I am trying to add:

```
[root@distribute1 network-scripts]# cat route-bond0.2102
161.26.98.0/24 via 10.95.32.1
10.246.179.0/24 via 10.246.182.65 dev bond0.2102
10.246.180.0/24 via 10.246.182.65 dev bond0.2102
10.246.181.0/24 via 10.246.182.65 dev bond0.2102
10.246.182.0/24 via 10.246.182.65 dev bond0.2102
```

Below are the errors I am seeing when I am restarting network services:

```
Bringing up interface bond0.2102:  Determining if ip address 10.246.182.2 is already in use for device bond0.2102...
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
```

Below are the existing routes:

```
[root@distribute1 network-scripts]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.50.33.104    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 bond0
10.246.182.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 bond0.2102
10.50.32.224    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 bond0
10.95.32.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 bond0.2455
161.26.98.0     10.95.32.1      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 bond0.2455
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 bond0
0.0.0.0         10.50.32.225    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 bond0
```

Kindly let what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

What I am missing is IP address assigned to interface **bond0.2102**.

Anyway from the routing table there is available one not (but "almost") related route:

```
10.246.182.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 bond0.2102
```

This route is the most probably going from IP address assigned to the interface. The network available on this interface is 10.246.182.0/27 (10.246.182.0 - 10.246.182.31).

In case you want to add the route to routing table the next hop (gateway) have to be directly reachable. In case you want to add some route not directly reachable you have to add record with the reachable node and that node have to know about the next step (again it has to be directly reachable for the mentioned node).

You are trying to add the route with the gw 10.246.182.65. Based on your current routing table the IP 10.246.182.65 is simply not reachable. The possible root of the issue is:

- GW IP 10.246.182.65. To heave it working the last octet (number after last dot) should be between 0 and 31 which is reachable by the current routing records
- netmask set up on the interface bond0.2102. In case there would be (max) /25 (now there is /27) the IP 10.246.182.65 would be reachable by the local records - for 10.246.182.0/25 the valid IP range would be 10.246.182.0 - 10.246.182.127.

As the last route you are trying to add is

```
10.246.182.0/24 via 10.246.182.65 dev bond0.2102
```

I guess the issue would be in the netmask set up on the interface. Once there would be IP address 10.246.182.x/24 instead the 10.246.182.x/27 the last listed route is not needed as it would be route implicitly "generated" based on IP setting on the interface and with this rule the IP 10.246.182.65 would be covered and working. As a result there would be route:

```
10.246.182.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 bond0.2102
```

instead of

```
10.246.182.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 bond0.2102
```